# Installing a laravel app on ec2 with lamp set up

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, laravel-5

Hello i sucessfully got a laravel 5 app running on my localhost perfectly, but when i try to deploy it on an ec2 ubuntu instance that already has lamp setup, I get an error coming from a try catch block i added, apparently the error is coming from the view finder not seeing my view file, here is the top most part of my stack trace

```
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php(79): Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder->findInPaths('install.compati...', Array) #1


/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Factory.php(165): Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder->find('install.compati...') #2
```

so im thinking maybe there is an ec2 extra configuration in need to add?.

Please any thoughts are welcome

Comment: Be little more elaborate. Which try catch block? Paste the code. Are you able to visit and see the landing page in your browser? And by the way from the path shown in the error you have uploaded the entire laravel project into the public folder on your ec2 server which is a big security risk.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Donkarnash, but i figured out the issue, and can you please explain more on what you mean by the public folder, thanks

Comment: Hey @carrion, `/var/www` or `/var/www/html` is generally configured with file permissions which allow unrestricted access to the contents within. But I realised that since you have a vps (ec2), you have full control over the permissions. You can set the file permissions such that only the `public` folder of your laravel project or for that matter any other site which you upload has unrestricted access while the root folder of your project/site is restricted to only the owner/group.

Comment: ah yes, thank you very much for that insight, i didn't even think of that @Donkarnash

Answer (score 0):

As @Donkarnash said, the problem was just too broad.i figured out the problem, well the problems, i had a lot of issues on it, first i didn't have mcrypt setup on my lamp setup on Ubuntu, and then i had to use artisan to clear cache, after which i had to generate a new key and then it was working perfectly, although it still apparently has a big security risk